# Should I use Collapsible Panels on Landing Page or something else?

Tags: usability, landing-page, conversion-rate, choices, collapsible-panels

I am looking to build a landing page for new users from advertising. On my site, there are several ways to get what you want -- all of them equal weight from my perspective -- but with different ways to go about each.

For example, say I own a site to adopt cats, and there are 5 ways to do so:

1. Select from cats we currently have
2. Look through cats that have been adopted in the past to find one similar
3. Choose a recommended breeder to breed you a cat
4. Let several breeders reach out to you
5. Rent a cat

How can I maximize getting a new user to do one of the above tasks?
My first thought was something like a [PanelBar](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/panelbar/index.html) for easy switching (then A/B test which option to default expand), but I'm not sure.

Do you have a recommendation? (This is targeting Desktop only, for now)

Comment: can you tell me if the site is for PC or hand held devices or both?

Comment: Rent a cat?  What is this site, really?

Comment: Do you want the user to select a section to view its details of just load the first section when he comes to the page. Consider your panel bar, so do you want the user to click on a section and view its details or just show the list of currently available cats as the default view ?

Comment: I'd rent a cat.

Comment: @dan1111 there are cafes around in parts of the world where you can just go and cuddle cats (if you don't already own one, or even if you do). In fact I think Japan has stepped it up with a hedgehog cafe where you can even adopt them to take home!

Answer (score 1):

Landing pages are typically focused on ONE type of customer. Additional/ parallel customers would need their own landing pages. So ideally, you'd be focusing on getting the user to do one thing.

More options on a page doesn't translate into more interaction from users; it takes away the user's intent. If you go through the landing pages featured on [Landbook](http://land-book.com/), you'll see this theory in action.

For marketplaces vying for both customers and vendors/ suppliers, this is a problem. Should [Airbnb's](https://www.airbnb.com/) landing page be about renting private houses, or listing a house on their site? It turns out, they'd address the larger/ primary customer market on their site, with a button 'List your space' at the top right of the page, out of the centre of action.

Too much choice can often mean [the user refuses to make a choice](http://unbounce.com/conversion-rate-optimization/psychology-of-choice-conversion-rates/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned the different selections having equal weight in importance, I would present them equally on the page.

Better possible options:

- A standard menu, with short descriptions underneath each option
- Radio buttons if you want the user to only choose one option and then
  move on to the next step

Users spend very little time on landing pages so I would avoid hiding anything with panels.

Comment: Trtue on radio button part. But it can restructured as a navigation vertical carousal as in http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/news/ceo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

All item having equal weightage may be quiet true but without knowing the real estate that it might take in the page it is not possible to answer perfectly. I'll also assume that all elements take up equal real estate. In this case the internal page navigation with fixed submenu bar can be used. One of the best way using that is explained in this site https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira By doing so you always keep a tab so that the users are not lost and you do not over  crowd the page.

Answer (score 0):

Small images of the cats with few details should be on the main page. The pictures could be linked back to relevant details page giving further complete details about the cat and its owner. Navigation could mention different breeds as categories to help navigate to select specific breed cats.

Answer (score 0):

They sound like 5 distinct ways of adopting a cat. I would show them equally and not hide 4 out of 5 under a menu. Possibly like the layout below:

[image: Column layout]

Comment: If you can add a graphic /screenshot. If the link rots this answer would no longer have value.

Comment: The link shows a screenshot sample UI. There are 4 distinct columns of data, each a column for displaying and explaining an adoption option. In this case you would need 5 columns.